# Не удается неявно преобразовать тип UnityEngine.Light в UnityEngine.GameObject

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, unity3d

На сцене есть Dir Light и в инспекторе свойство Light. Нужно получить доступ к этому свойству для того, чтобы в дальнейшем менять значения при помощи кода.

Но выдает такую ошибку, когда я пытаюсь получить доступ:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это решить?

Код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DayNight : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Light;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Light = GameObject.Find("Directional Light");
        Light = gameObject.GetComponent<Light>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: `public Light light;`. А потом в коде `light = gameObject.GetComponent<Light>();`

Comment: благодарю вас за помощь